tanstack useQuery shows old data even after refetching
I have code
const activeFiles = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["active_files", projectId],
  queryFn: () => getActiveFiles(projectId),
  enabled: true,
  refetchOnWindowFocus: false
});

A separate component has
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
return useMutation({
  .......
  onSuccess: async() => {
    await queryClient = invalidateQueries({
      queryKey: ["active_files", projectId]
    });
    anotherFunction();
  },
});

The onSuccess function was run, then I waited a couple seconds and clicked a button that would use the value in activeFiles. But activeFiles.data was old and activeFiles.isStale was true. I thought that it would put the new value into the query. Am I missing a step?
I made sure it was the same projectId.
Using breakpoints I made sure that getActiveFiles was executed and returned new data, then reached anotherFunction, but the activeFiles access afterward still gave me old data.
I tried adding await activeFiles.refetch(); before accessing activeFiles and it did not help.  I made sure the getActiveFiles function output was a brand new array by wrapping its return value like [...results], and that did not help.  I tried putting staleTime: 0 into the useQuery or refetchType: "all" into the invalidateQueries and that did not help.
When I did await activeFiles.refetch.then((files)=>{......}) then files had the new fresh data. But I think invalidateQueries should have removed the need for me to manually refetch like this, and this strategy also required the getActiveFiles function to run again. How do I make it automatically put the new obtained value into the query?
Edit:
It may be important to mention that activeFiles is being accessed inside
async function handleExit() {
  .......[there are no awaits before this point]
  await possiblyDelayedFunction(activeFiles.data);
}

useEffect(() => {
  .......
  return function cleanup() {
    handleExit();
  };
}, []);



I see a typo in the onSuccess callback ansyc.
I also see that you are doing
    await queryClient = invalidateQueries({
      queryKey: ["active_files", projectId]
    });

when it should be
queryClient.invalidateQueries({
      queryKey: ["active_files", projectId]
    });

I would also check that projectId matches in both the query and the mutation onSuccess. To test this theory, I would suggest calling queryClient.invalidateQueries() with no arguments to invalidate all queries and see if that works.
The last thing to note is that invalidateQueries will not cause the other original useQuery to call itself, however you said its in a different component, so if it rerenders it will call the useQuery hook again and refetch it. However the hook may not be getting called, and therefore you may need to manually call refetch() as you have outlined in your question, as opposed to just invalidating the query.
As an additional step:
I'd also suggest maybe using the response of the mutation to just update the query cache as it would save you a call to the backend and look faster.

The async typo is just in this post, not in the original code.  I removed the redundant await, and made the invalidateQueries empty.  Then I checked with breakpoints to confirm that the useQuery method was being constantly called.  The useQuery is inside a functional component that I think is being rerendered.  It is at least calling useQuery many times between the invalidateQueries and the access of its value.

Maybe an important detail is that the value of activeFiles is being accessed inside
useEffect(() => {
...
return function cleanup() {
[accessing activeFiles]
};
}, []);

I added that info and fixed the typo in the post.
